# How to capture the cursor position in a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, textbox

I have a TextChanged event on my Masked TextBox and I want its method to be called just when the cursor stay at the end.

For example:

222.222.2/21

The event shall be called as soon as the user types "1".

XAML

```
<TextBox
                Name="myTextBox"
                ToolTip="type here"
                Height="30"
                Width="100"
                FontSize="14"
                MaxLength="12"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                TextChanged="MyMethod"/>
```

C#

```
 private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e){
     if (myTextBox.Text.Length == myTextBox.MaxLength)
        {
            //how do I know if the cursor is at the end?
        }
    }
```

SOLUTION

```
private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e){
     if (myTextBox.Text.Length == myTextBox.MaxLength)
        {
            if(process.CaretIndex == 12)
            {
               //do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By cursor, you mean mouse?

Comment: I mean the cursor that shows when you type in a textbox. The "|' cursor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`myTextBox.CaretIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myTextBox.Text.Length == myTextBox.MaxLength)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"caret is at {myTextBox.CaretIndex}");
    }
}
```